# Как создать последовательную цепь из слов-ключей?

Tags: python

[image: Как должно выглядеть]

Допустим. Я создал словарь, и у каждого слова есть два ключа. Возможно ли построить цепь из слов, с последовательными ключами 1, 2 > 2, 4 > 4, 1; 2, 4 > 4, 1 > 1, 2; используя random?

Comment: рандом-то тут причём? сделайте словарь, в котором ключом будет in, тогда нетрудно построить цепь, находя пару к out

Comment: @MBo, если не сложно, можете скинуть пример пожалуйста? А рандом для того чтобы каждый раз получались случайные цепи. У меня просто будет больше слов.

Comment: тогда в элементе словаря должен быть ключ in и список слов с этим in. А рандомом уже из этого списка выбирать.

Comment: ааа, дошло плюс минус. для каждого числа свой словарь?

Comment: нет, один словарь. ключ - левое число (in), для него список списков или кортежей {1:[("rock", 3), ("quack",5)],  3:[("lemon", 2), ("apple",1),("pear",7)],  и т.д.}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопрос и зачем тут random, но походу вам нужно что-то подобное?

```
words = {
    3: ['apple', 1],
    1: ['rock', 2],
    2: ['land', 4],
}

index = 3

while index in words:
    block = words[index]
    
    print(block[0])
    index = block[1]
```

В комментариях был задан вопрос об ограничении цепи. В таком случае немного подредактируем цикл:

```
length = 5

while index in words and length > 0:
    # Все, что было до этого
    length -= 1
```

P.S. Это при условии, что цепь непрерывна и без циклов, т.е. от каждого input мы приходим в одно и только одно слово, из которого выходим по одному и только одному output

Comment: рандом чтобы всегда были разные цепи

Comment: и еще, огрооомное спасибо

Comment: я добавил такие же слова ключи (переименованные ), выбирались только последние, рандома нету. и еще можно ограничить длинну цепи?

Comment: @Tripletree Вы могли все написать в одном комментарии:) 1: Если хотите рандом, то просто запускайте цикл с рандомного числа. 2: Пожалуйста. 3: про ограничение добавил в ответ. Если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, примите его, нажав галочку слева.

Comment: А почему в таком случае, выбирается не случайно, а последнее подходящее по индексу?     words = {
    3: ['apple', 1],
    1: ['rock', 2],
    2: ['land', 4],
    2: ['sifa', 3],
    3: ['folt', 2]
}

index = 2

length = 5

while index in words and length > 0:
    block = words[index]
    
    print(block[0])
    index = block[1]
    length -= 1              >>>sifa folt sifa folt sifa   upd: извините за беспокойство опять, пожалуйста

Comment: @Tripletree Мой код работает только если цепочка (нарисованная у вас в вопросе) **линейна**. А у вас в от двойки можно прийти сразу в два блока! В таком случае как по вашему должно код понять в какой блок ему приходить? Лично я под рандомом понимал, что НАЧИНАЕТСЯ вывод с рандомного блока, а дальше идет линейно. Если так, то нужно просто присваивать `index` на рандомное число из ключей словаря `words`. Но вам похоже нужен не такой рандом. В любом случае мой код работает с линейной цепью, а вы мне в коментарии написали совсем другое (см. выше). Тут нужен другой код, но тогда и задача непонятна

Comment: в любом случае спасибо!!